# Global Exception Handler in ASP.NET Core Web API 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

This [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1) talks about error handling for ASP.NET Core apps.  But it is focused on pages and responses.  I have a slightly different need.

I need to be very sure that if there are unhanded errors, that I log them.  (Right now my service is failing under a load test with no indication in the logs as to why or where.)

With all the `Task`s being called, I am guessing that there are some lost exceptions in the mix.

**Is there an "unhanded exceptions" call back for ASP.NET Core (v3.1)?**  (So I can log the exception.)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Exception Filter. See this documentation: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1#exception-filters